# Error in Powershell with .recycle() method

Tags: powershell, recycle-bin, exception

With the following code, I am getting this error in powershell:
I could not find out whats wrong here? I am using recycle() method because in next step, i need to restore items from recycle bin.

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId] doesn't contain a method named 'recycle'.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Test.ps1:76 char:9
+         $DeletedItem = $ListItems[$i].recycle()
```

---

```
Function Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT
{
    $Global:site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object {

     $PagesLibrary = $_.Lists[$Global:lookForList]

    if($PagesLibrary -ne $null)
    {

        if($PagesLibrary.ContentTypes[$Global:CT_To_Add_Remove])
        {
            $Global:site_To_AddCT = $_.Url
            $PagesLibrary.AllowDeletion = $true
            $NewsPageCT = $PagesLibrary.ContentTypes[$Global:CT_To_Add_Remove]

                if($NewsPageCT -ne $null)
                {               

                    $iD = $NewsPageCT | Select Id
                    $idString = $iD.Id.ToString()
                    $ListItems = $PagesLibrary.Items | Where-Object { $_.ContentTypeId -eq $idString }

                    Remove-NewsPageCT $ListItems, $NewsPageCT, $PagesLibrary, $idString
                }
            $Global:TotalSitesWithNewsPageCT++
        }

    }
    $Global:Total_Sites
    }

    Write-Host "Total Sites are: " $Global:Total_Sites
    Write-Host "Total Sites to Remove/Add NewsPage content type: " $Global:TotalSitesWithNewsPageCT
}

Function Remove-NewsPageCT
{
    param($ListItems,$NewsPageCT,$PagesLibrary,$idString)

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$DeletedItemsIDs = @()
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$DeletedItems = @()
    $count = 0

    if($ListItems.Count -gt 0)
    {
        for($i = $ListItems.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
        {
            $DeletedItemsIDs.Add($ListItems[$i].ID)
            $DeletedItem = $ListItems[$i].recycle()       
            $DeletedItems.add($DeletedItem)
            $count++             
        }
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    $NewsPageCT.ReadOnly = $false
    $NewsPageCT.Update()
    $PagesLibrary.ContentTypes.Delete($idString)
    $PagesLibrary.Update()

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    Add-NewsPageCT $PagesLibrary $DeletedItemsIDs $DeletedItems $count

}
```

Comment: Check what items you've got in the $DeletedItem array. Seems there might be something else mixed between list items.

Comment: sounds like a $ListItems problem. perhaps you could show how you're populating that

Comment: @TiagoDuarte: I have updated my question

Comment: apparently your ListItems array doesnt contain items of type SPListItem as it should. could either be some code specific issue, or memory issue. try closing your IDE if you use any, close any shells and run the script again form a clean console

Comment: I have already closed the IDE and started Powershell again, but still same error.

Comment: the script, as you put it, seems to be fine. I would still bet on an environmental issue. also, why does your remove function have 4 parameters when you apparently only need one? as a last resort, I would remove the where-object statement and wrap an if-condition around the "for" statements to check the behaviour (or populate listitems inside the remove function). powershell sometimes messes up your return data so you need to make sure that what you send is what you get. watch out for outputted data. I prefer to use "| out-null" when I don't need the result. also, GetType() is your friend

Comment: @TiagoDuarte: The reason why i put 4 parameters, actually i am using other parameters in the function that i dont mention here. I have updated question with full code now

Comment: I would move the ListItems population into the remove function, instead of sending it as a parameter. you're already sending the required parameters anyway

Comment: @TiagoDuarte: I have just remove the code from Remove-NewsPageCT function and put directly in  this function Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT. so now i am not passing any value, but still same error??? starnage..

Comment: can't reproduce it. same code works fine here. try adding the whole script. don't omit anything. variables, etc. you can also try if you haven't already, to run the script on a brand new, separate shell, without using the IDE